# How to find $\int \frac {\sinh(\ln x)} {2x}\,dx$?

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I've tried

$$\int \frac  {\sinh(\ln x)} {2x}\,dx = \int \frac  {e^{\ln x}-e^{-\ln x}} {2x}\,dx =  \int \frac  {x-e^{-\ln x}} {2x}\,dx$$

Comment: Try substituting $u=\ln x$ instead.

Comment: $e^{-\ln(x)}=1/x$.

Comment: $e^{-\ln{x}}=1/x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prove that $$\sinh(\ln(x))=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2x}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you set $t=\ln x$, then $dt=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int \sinh t\,dt = \cosh t+c=\cosh \ln x+c
$$
Then you can transform this as you please:
$$
\cosh\ln x=\frac{e^{\ln x}+e^{-\ln x}}{2}=\frac{x+1/x}{2}=\frac{x^2+1}{2x}
$$

With your original attempt, you just have to recognize that $e^{-\ln x}=\dfrac{1}{x}$